# Which PGP key does thunderbird 78 choose for encryption?

Tags: pgp

In our project, we use thunderbird 78 and PGP for encrypted mailing. On my computer, there are two PGP keys valid for the same email-address, both not expired and marked as trusted absolutely. One was created in 2018, the other in 2021.

How does thunderbird select the key to encrypt the email?

In my test (78.11.0 (64-bit), MacOS) thunderbird selected the older key to encrypt the email. I had expected the creation date (the newer the better) as a criteria for key selection. But obviously it's another strategy. Does anybody know if it's documented or in which source file it's implemented?

I also filed this in Bugzilla:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1718905

Comment: indeed, it makes more sense in superuser. I added reference to Version and MacOS. Thx for transferring!